# Changing an array in Javascript does not update my vue list

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have been building a vue 3 app with nuxt 3. With websockets to update data from the server to the webpage. Now I tried to add a list that updates itself when it gets new data but I cannot get it to work.

To find the problem I have minimized the code to the following example to understand the problem. It still isn't working. It starts with a one entry array. The page has a button and clicking the button adds another entry. But the list does not update.

This is inside a vue component that is shown on the main app.vue.

The commented blocks were from other tries when scribbeling around to get it to work.

Code:

```
<script setup>

import '/js/control.js';
import '/js/websocket';
// let items = [{
//   "timestamp": "b",
//   "Message":"Hallo",
//   "SourceInfo": "",
//   "Counter":0
// }];
data: () => (items = 
 [{
   "timestamp": "b",
   "Message":"Hallo",
   "SourceInfo": "",
   "Counter":0
 }])

 const items = 
 [{
   "timestamp": "b",
   "Message":"Hallo",
   "SourceInfo": "",
   "Counter":0
 }]
// export default {
//   data: {
// let    items = 
//  [{
//    "timestamp": "b",
//    "Message":"Hallo",
//    "SourceInfo": "",
//    "Counter":0
//  }]


function more() {
  console.log(items);
  items.push({
  "timestamp": "r",
  "Message":"b",
  "SourceInfo": "",
  "Counter":0
});

}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="someclass">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items">
        {{item.timestamp}} - {{item.Message}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="more">more</button>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.someclass {
  /* background-image: url('/SW4_EG.jpg'); */
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 983px;
  height: 537px; */
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You need to make your `items` reactive by using `ref()` or `reactive()`.  https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html

Comment: @Gabe I can get it to work with reactive() but not with ref() and an array. Even after reading your link. Do you have a link to an example with ref and extendable array? I always find examples for vue 2 but none with the script-setup tag. So they always use export default in a script tag. I want to try the script-setup tag.

Comment: @Gabe Now I got it. Forgot to add :ref to the for and using the items I need items.value to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work after trying another couple of things. As @Gabe stated the sample in the question works with reactive().

like:

```
const items = reactive(... array ...);
```

And with ref I got it to work with the following changes:

```
<script setup>

import '/js/control.js';
import '/js/websocket';
// let items = [{
//   "timestamp": "b",
//   "Message":"Hallo",
//   "SourceInfo": "",
//   "Counter":0
// }];
data: () => (items = 
 [{
   "timestamp": "b",
   "Message":"Hallo",
   "SourceInfo": "",
   "Counter":0
 }])

 const items = ref
 (
 [{
   "timestamp": "b",
   "Message":"Hallo",
   "SourceInfo": "",
   "Counter":0
 }]);
// // export default {
//   data: {
// let    items = 
//  [{
//    "timestamp": "b",
//    "Message":"Hallo",
//    "SourceInfo": "",
//    "Counter":0
//  }]


function more() {
  console.log(items);
  items.value.push({   <<<<<<<< changed
  "timestamp": "r",
  "Message":"b",
  "SourceInfo": "",
  "Counter":0
});

}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="someclass">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" :ref="items">  <<<<<<<< changed
        {{item.timestamp}} - {{item.Message}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="more">more</button>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.someclass {
  /* background-image: url('/SW4_EG.jpg'); */
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 983px;
  height: 537px; */
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This `:ref="items"` is a really strange way to use ref in your template, since you are creating a template ref with a dynamic binding to a data object / array. It should work without it. Besides that you should add a unique key to your v-for elements, e.g. with `:key="item.timestamp"`.

Comment: @Gabe I know about the key and had used it. But in the end I stripped everything and put everything into one template to find my problem. Actually I don't know yet what the : colon is for. I took it from a sample in the documentation. I will try leaving it away. In the end the items array should not be defined in here but would be filled by a websocket that is used outside. Still working on a solution for all that.